# Different rewrite rules in apache for different subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

currently I get mad on Apache rewrite rules again. My problem is, that I want to have different rewrite rules for different subdomains, but I only have one `.htaccess` file (limited by my provider).

What I mean is: I have subdomain `A` and I want to define some rewrite rules that only match if the subdomain matched beforehand. Same for subdomain `B`, `C`, ... (doesn't matter how much subdomains I have).

I tried it on two ways: first I tried it with a combination of `<If>` directives and `mod_rewrite`, second I tried it by setting an enviroment variable that is set differently related to the matching subdomain.

First version (the readable one):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  <If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'example.org'">
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </If>

  <If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'blog.example.org'">
    # /autor/{author name}
    RewriteRule ^/autor/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?author_name=$1 [L]

    # /{blog name}
    RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?blog=$1 [L]

    # /{blog name}/{year}/{article name}
    RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([0-9]{4})/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?blog=$1&year=$2&name=$3 [L]

    # /
    RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php?post_type=post [L]
  </If>
</IfModule>
```

Second version (the ugly one):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  # set enviroment variable SUBDOMAIN for different subdomains
  # subdomain: example.org
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} "=example.org"
  RewriteRule . - [ENV=SUBDOMAIN:main]

  # subdomain: assets.roter-baum.de
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} "=assets.roter-baum.de"
  RewriteRule . - [ENV=SUBDOMAIN:assets]

  # subdomain: blog.example.org
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} "=blog.example.org"
  RewriteRule . - [ENV=SUBDOMAIN:blog]


  # rules for main
  RewriteCond %{ENV:SUBDOMAIN} "=main"
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

  RewriteCond %{ENV:SUBDOMAIN} "=main"
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

  # rules for blog
  # /autor/{author name}
  RewriteCond %{ENV:SUBDOMAIN} "=blog"
  RewriteRule ^/autor/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?author_name=$1 [L]

  # /{blog name}
  RewriteCond %{ENV:SUBDOMAIN} "=blog"
  RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?blog=$1 [L]

  # /{blog name}/{year}/{article name}
  RewriteCond %{ENV:SUBDOMAIN} "=blog"
  RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([0-9]{4})/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?blog=$1&year=$2&name=$3 [L]

  # /
  RewriteCond %{ENV:SUBDOMAIN} "=blog"
  RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php?post_type=post [L]
```

The point is: it works as long as I don't point to the `index.php`. When I link to `index.php` I get a 500 Internal Server Error and I don't know why. Any ideas? I mean, I would also use the ugly version if I have to and if it works. But currently none are working.

Comment: _"I get a 500 Internal Server Error and I don't know why."_ - then go and check what the error log has to say!

Comment: @CBroe That would be easy if I had access to the log. Unfortunately this is not the case.